# Display jenkins dashboard in client web browser

Tags: azure, jenkins

I have a build server with Jenkins running as a Windows Service.
It runs at the local 8080 port.
I want to be able to view the jobs dashboard at any machine by typing the correspondent address in a web browser.
Something like {DNS}:8080/myView.

What I need to define in the Jenkins/Azure to make this happen?

Comment: Put the Jenkin node behind a LB or else change the NSG(firewall) rules. Ideally speaking it should run in 80/443 port, or else your client machine might block it because of security issue(in this case tunneling will help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 moving parts here, you don't really have to do anything on Jenkins part, apart from running it:

1. VM should have public IP, or you should have some kind of routing to the VM on the port you are interested in.
2. Network Security Group should permit traffic on the port of interest (8080) (both on the Subnet and on the Network interface) [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal)
3. Firewall on the VM should allow traffic on the port of interest.
4. Application on the VM (Jenkins in your case) should listen to the traffic on the port of interest.

Comment: 1. VM has a public dynamic ip which gets successfully resolved when pinging the DNS public name. Is that enough?

2. Added an NSG and associated it with the VM

3. Disabled the firewall at the VM altogether for now.

4. What application?

Comment: yeah, looks fine. 4 - in your case - Jenkins; did you configure NSG to allow traffic on 8080?

Comment: 4. This step is unclear to me. If I browse to localhost:8080 at the VM I'm able to view the Jenkins pages. Does that mean Jenkins is listening to the 8080 port?

Yes an inbound any service traffic on 8080

Comment: OK.
So all 4 moving parts are in place but still no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135091/discussion-between-gena-verdel-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one have to add an endpoint at the Azure VM. In any case, that's what's worked for me.